# Is どこ住み ever pronounced どこずみ?

Tags: pronunciation, readings, rendaku

I have been saying どこ住み{ずみ} as in ～さん、どこずみですか？ because I seem to remember the first few times I heard the word used by other people it was pronounced as such. And I haven't had any issues making myself understood. But I have been hearing どこ住み{すみ} recently, which does seem to be the correct pronunciation. But is the word ever pronounced どこずみ?

Comment: 個人的には「どこすみ」の方が自然に感じます。でもどっちでも構わないと思います。

Comment: 私も、「どこすみ」って読みます。まあどっちでもいいと思いますが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ずみ is the more common pronunciation.

Since it is a very colloquial word, it can deviate from ordinary rules, but it seems reasonable to assume 連濁 happens just as in a proper word [部屋住み](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%83%A8%E5%B1%8B%E4%BD%8F%E3%81%BF).